# ASP.NET Core 3: cannot run on linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core

I have created a small ASP.NET Core 3.0 self-contained app console.
Build for Windows - it works.
But when publish for linux, copy and run it in linux then I receive:

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.0.0' was not found.
```

Check the files: really, no this file in the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed the latest update for the VS2019, installed the NET Core 3.1 SDK. Then have rebuilt the project, publish it for linux, copied and run on Linux. It works. No any Microsoft.AspNetCore.App requirement anymore. It seems VS2019 Preview bug.